# Searching question marks in man

Tags: man, search

I did `man maldet` trying to get information about (what I can call) `maldet wildcards` which are represented by question marks.

I clicked `/` and searched `\?` and also for `"\?"`, but nothing was found even though the man pages clearly contain question marks.

Given I used an escaping metacharacter and it the search still failed, I ask here why.

I should note that other patterns, like "batch" for example, were found without problems.

The reason I searched for a question mark is to find a command containing it.

Comment: Which pager are you using?

Comment: Hmm, both on my local and remote Linux, when I did ``echo $pager`` I got an empty row as stdout (if it is even logical to call it stdout?)...

Comment: I ask only because you didn't actually mention it: did you try searching without escaping the question mark at all?

Comment: Yes, at the start I didn't think of escaping it --- But still, there were no results.

Comment: Try `echo $MANPAGER`, and let us know the result

Comment: Again - in both cases, empty row as stdout.

Comment: What Linux flavour are you running? On mine my pager is `less` and I could search for question marks with `/\?`. Try `MANPAGER=less man maldet` or `man --pager=less maldet` and see if that helps.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.04 but good news, I haven't tried the 2 commands above but now when I did just `man maldet`, and searched for `\?` after clicking `/`, I did find these. Maybe I missed that earlier, maybe another reason, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have problems with your pager. Try `MANPAGER=less man maldet` or `man --pager=less maldet` and see if that helps. To make it permanent, in your `.bashrc` put the following line: `export MANPAGER=less`